# Why my computer subnet works like this?

Tags: subnet

When I type "ipconfig" within my command line, I get this thing:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.102.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.102.1
```

Why tha hack my subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 and my IP CLASS is A?
Because this thing, I have 2^16  of network prefix and 2^8 hosts can be - which is wnormous number I will never use!
How can I make my IP to be class C (to be able to host only 2^8 hosts, and then subnneting this IP to be \29 so I my network will be able to hold just 5 computers trying to connect.?)?

Comment: classful addressing is dead for 24 years, forget about it and learn CIDR. Note that home networking is off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a mask `255.255.255.0`, it means that the range of addresses is from `10.100.102.0`to `10.100.102.255`.

In 1993, the Internet Engineering Task Force published RFC 1518 and RFC 1519. These RFCs define a new concept called **Classless Inter Domain Routing**. The most important thing of those RFCs is that obsoletes the **Classful Network** where ranges where associated with classes with fixed netmasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ip is in the 10 range because it belongs to the group of private IP, which are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16. Since this ranges are not routed onto to the public network you can do whatever you want with this ips on your home or office network.